# Limit Request by IP on Codeigniter Rest API Server (chriskacerguis)

Tags: codeigniter, api

According to this github from chriskacerguis (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/issues/710) ,

anyone knows how to limit request by IP ?
Curently the API only limit by request per user/key.

```
 $this->methods['user_get']['limit'] = 500; // 500 requests per hour per user/key
    $this->methods['user_post']['limit'] = 100; // 100 requests per hour per user/key
    $this->methods['user_delete']['limit'] = 50; // 50 requests per hour per user/key
```

Is this possible to create limitation by IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Chris already updated his Codeigniter,
now i can limit request by IP.

Here is the docs : https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/commit/706f3b8375a0f6d1c65224dc112429f02037a572

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).